# ls colors for permissions

Tags: shell, ls, colors

Is there a way to control the color output of ls to highlight specific permissions on files? (e.g. **write** permissions).

[image]

Any options in `LS_COLORS` that would do this? (the image above is from Dired+ on Emacs 24.1, not from the output of `ls`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always put `ls` [on stereoids](https://github.com/trapd00r/ls--) to achieve the coloring effect of file permissions.

Comment: More modern solution: https://github.com/ogham/exa

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried it, and this is actually possible with a little Ruby program called [acoc](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/acoc.shtml) (Arbitrary Command Output Colourer). It can be used to intercept output from any terminal program (colourised output in `top` and `gcc` is particularly neat) and colourise them according to a file of user-specified regular expression rules. It is a bit of work to set up, and you'll have to define your rules, but this is about as flexible as it gets. I was able to successfully add a rule to colourise world-writable files.

A couple of caveats to be aware of if you go down this route:

1. This project doesn't seem to be in any distribution - you'll have to install manually from the homepage.
2. You need to patch the code on the project homepage to work with modern versions of Ruby. You can find the patch [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=23352) (I've contacted the author to let him know of the patch, perhaps he'll update his version).
3. In the case of `ls`, intercepting with `acoc` throws away the existing `LS_COLORS`, so you'll have to provide all the rules you need as regular expressions, including things that used to be highlighted with `LS_COLORS`.

Answer (score 1):

If `dircolors --print-database` lists all possible options, there's no way to highlight permissions in long output.

You can still use grep:

`ls -l | grep --color -P "(?<=[r-])w"`

It will highlight all `w`s in the permissions part; it will also highlight `w`s following `r`s and `-`s in the file name, alas.

Comment: Looks great. I wonder if there is a way to update this so that it only matches the first hit on a white-space splitting of each line. Wouldn't that do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for. Some time ago I wrote a script that works as "ls" but shows some nice colors for permissions in the output. You can read about it [here](http://mountpeaks.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/lls/), download it [here](http://lls.googlecode.com/files/lls). I keep it in /usr/local/bin. If you're a debian|ubuntu based distro user, replace #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash in the script;) Ask, if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

https://altbox.dev/ also mentions [`lsd`](https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd) and [`exa`](https://github.com/ogham/exa) among `ls++` (see user13742's answer) as a replacement for `ls` to accomplish this task. Both are written in Rust and offer pre-compiled binaries. I have not tried them myself yet, I'm just researching the tool chain of a course instructor.